# Two string permutation

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

The question is based on topic "permutation of strings". There are two questions, each of which I believe are similar:

Question1 (from CTCI) : Given two strings, write a method to decide if one is a permutation of the other.

Conditions: case sensitive and whitespace significant

permutation definition: If two strings are permutations , then we know they have same characters, but in different orders. Also, they have same character count.

Question2 (from leetcode): Given two strings s1 and s2, write a function to return true if s2 contains the permutation of s1. In other words, one of the first string's permutations is the substring of the second string.

```
Example 1: Input:s1 = "ab" s2 = "eidbaooo" 
Output:True 
Explanation: s2 contains one permutation of s1 ("ba").

Example 2:
Input:s1= "ab" s2 = "eidboaoo"
Output: False
```

Condition:
The input strings only contain lower case letters.

### The length of both given strings is in range [1, 10,000].

Here is my question. One Question1 states strings should of same size while other (Question2 example) shows they should be different. Which one is correct and why.

Also if asked in interview, which way (statement)  will take forward this problem?

Comment: Neither is more correct than the other; they are just two different sets of requirements

Comment: @GBlodgett Where is the catch in questions that makes them different?

Comment: The first means that the characters in the string will be same, but in a different order (permutation) - no extra characters. The second is a more general version of the first where the permutation could occur anywhere in the string, with extra characters being present as well. If you solve the second, you have solved the first (just restricting both inputs to have same length).

Comment: @aditya What do you mean? They are two different problems with different requirements. Neither is correct per say

Comment: @GBlodgett I was confused by this definition: "permutation definition: If two strings are permutations , then we know they have same characters, but in different orders. Also, they have same character count." . Same character count....

Answer (score 2):

These are two different problems that could be solved in different ways:

- The first problem has a quick solution of sorting both strings and comparing the results.
- The second problem is slightly harder - you could solve it by computing counts for each character in both strings, then checking that the counts for each character of the shorter string is less than or equal to the count of the corresponding character in the longer string.
- You can reuse the solution of the second problem to solve the first one simply by adding a check that both strings have the same length.

Comment: beautiful explanation. Thanks a lot:)